# GAE PHP Session Expiring too soon

Tags: php, google-app-engine, session

I am using a `SESSION` to store user data after a user logs in and should that data not be set, it would redirect the user the login page. After about 30 minutes of inactivity from the user, the `SESSION` gets wiped. How would I go about extending the `SESSION` time in `GAE` `PHP`? The `GAE` documentation doesn't seem to mention it.

Any input? Thanks!

EDIT: For whatever reason this was closed. Gwell's comment on this question works. For anyone else in the same situation.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed.. but here is the answer you need Guy. When it's re-opened I will post it as an official answer.

You can include a php.ini file with your project. 
Refer to: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini

In php.ini you can specify many settings, including the default session timeout.
session.gc_maxlifetime() is the setting you're looking for.

Comment: @Gwell Perfect! I knew I could do it on my local install, but I didn't think I could touch the GAE php.ini. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can include a php.ini file with your project. Refer to: developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini
In php.ini you can specify many settings, including the default session timeout. session.gc_maxlifetime() is the setting you're looking for